# Get file name from download URL click executed from my web page after user completes the save operation?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a Javascript based web page where I let the user save the contents of a text area to a local file on their PC.  I am using the following code to facilitate that operation, which is executed when the user clicks on a SAVE button on the page:

```
/**
 * Save the given text content to a local file using the given file name.
 *
 * @param {String} textContent - The text content to save.
 * @param {String} fileName - The name of the file to use for saving the text content.
 * @param {String} contentType - The content type.
 */
function saveFileLocally(textContent, fileName, contentType) {
    let aTag = document.createElement("a");
    let file = new Blob([textContent], {type: contentType});
    
    aTag.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    aTag.download = fileName;
    aTag.click();
    
    // Store the MRU prompt file name.
    $('#mru-prompt-file-name-textarea').val(fileName);
}
```

If the user changes the file name from the suggested file name passed to the *saveFileLocally()* function then I have no idea anymore what the actual name of the save file is.

I want to get the file name that they saved to so I can store as cookie, so they don't have to specify the same file name again and again every time they just want to do a resave operation  to the same file.  Note: *I don't want the full path because I know that is a security issue*.  I am hoping that I can at least get the primary file name so I can store that to a cookie (E.g. - "my-document.txt").

How can I get the primary file name used in the download operation after the browser has facilitated the operation with a File Save dialog window?

If I can't do this using the technique embodied by my current code, is there another way to do this that would allow me access to the primary file name the user saved to?

Answer (score 0):

With the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) you are able to store strings of data in the browser of the client. The storage consists of items which are identified with keys which hold values in [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString).

If you want to persist the data on the client use the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) interface, otherwise use the session based [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Both these interface work with similar methods to retrieve and store the values.

In the example below I've made two abstractions with utilize the [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) methods of the `localStorage` interface to get and set the stored values.

```
/**
 * Key to store the fileName value in.
 */
const storedFileNameKey = 'fileName';

/**
 * Returns the local storage filename item in a string if it exists.
 * Otherwise it will return null.
 *
 * @returns {String|null}
 */
function getStoredFileName() {
  return localStorage.getItem(storedFileNameKey);
}

/**
 * Sets the local storage filename.
 *
 * @param {String} value - Value to store.
 */
function setStoredFileName(value) {
  localStorage.setItem(storedFileNameKey, value);
}
```

When your page is loaded you'll want to immediately check if the input field has to be prefilled with the stored value, if that value is present. `getItem` returns either a `DOMString` when a value is stored or `null` when the item does not exist.

```
(function() {

  // Retrieve and set stored fileName if stored.
  const fileName = getStoredFileName();
  if (fileName !== null) {
    $('#mru-prompt-file-name-textarea').val(fileName);
  }

})()
```

In your `saveFileLocally` function call the `setStoredFileName` function to store the `fileName` in the local storage. If `saveFileLocally` is called then the input field should be prefilled on reloading the page.

```
/**
 * Save the given text content to a local file using the given file name.
 *
 * @param {String} textContent - The text content to save.
 * @param {String} fileName - The name of the file to use for saving the text content.
 * @param {String} contentType - The content type.
 */
function saveFileLocally(textContent, fileName, contentType) {
    let aTag = document.createElement("a");
    let file = new Blob([textContent], {type: contentType});
    
    aTag.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    aTag.download = fileName;
    aTag.click();
    
    // Store the MRU prompt file name.
    setStoredFileName(fileName);
    $('#mru-prompt-file-name-textarea').val(fileName);
}
```